# Ionic2 Mailchimp API. Angular2 not post anything

Tags: php, angular, ionic2, mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

So the thing is I'm currently working on a mobile app with ionic2 and I have to use Mailchimp for subscriptions. I write a php file which handle the API and upload it on a server. The API is works fine with the static email that I write in it so it's actually working. After I made it I start to working on the post data in angular2/ionic2. But i get

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token A in JSON at position 0

error.

The whole thing is fail in this code:

```
createPost(post: {email: string}): Observable<any>{
    const email = JSON.stringify(post);
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:8100/api', email, {
        headers: headers
    }).map(res => {console.log(res.json())});
  }
```

I figure out the problem is the url but I can't figure out why. When I use http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts in the url it works.

My php code looks like this(I use MailChimnp.php wrapper):

```
<?php // for MailChimp API v3.0
include('MailChimp.php');  // path to API wrapper downloaded from GitHub
use \DrewM\MailChimp\MailChimp;

$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
$request = json_decode($postdata);
$email = $request->email;

$MailChimp = new MailChimp('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-usXX');

$list_id = 'xxxxxxxxxx';
$result = $MailChimp->post("lists/$list_id/members", [
                'email_address' => $email,
                'status'        => 'subscribed',
            ]);

print_r($result);

if ($MailChimp->success()) {
    print_r($result); 
} else {
    echo $MailChimp->getLastError();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your map function needs to return data. You have to fix this:

```
createPost(post: {email: string}): Observable<any>{
   const email = JSON.stringify(post);
   let headers = new Headers();
   headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
   return this.http.post('http://localhost:8100/api', email, {
      headers: headers
   }).map(res => {
      console.log(res.json())
      return res.json(); //add this line
   });
}
```

Comment: Have you subscribe somewhere on this function?

Comment: Yes I have and the funny thing I check the lists in the MailChimp and it's working. I still get this SyntaxError but its working.